# How to add a custom font to SpriteBuilder for ios and android (font appears on IOS)

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, apportable, spritebuilder

Hi All Hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong

My sprite builder version is 1.1.0 (not sure if that helps?)
xcode version is 5.1.1 (5B1008)
running cocos2d 3.1.0

I've tried some of the suggestions already on the forum here and on Spritebuilder

**1) in my spritebuilder file I have my font file "Flavors.ttf" added:**

[image: setup of my files in spritebuilder]

**2) I have checked the font name as you can see its real name is also "Flavors"**

[image]

**3) i have as suggested added to my configuration.json file to include the font**

[image]
[image]

**4)and checked the path that the files exist there**
[image]

**5) when I run the app the font doesn't appear**

**6)on console I type** apportable log:

I get this warning:

**Warning:** Parameter Source/Resources/Published-iOS/ccbResources/Flavors.ttf was not found in asset.

this is confusing since I can see the file in that location?
and even the info (right click on Flavors.ttf) Where the file is located is:
Source/Resources/Published-iOS/ccbResources - so to me it confirms the location of the font file...

if I build (apportable build)
I get this warning

**Warning:** Unable to find a file to match the following requested asset: /Users/Minty/Desktop/ProjectName7.spritebuilder/Source/Resources/Published-iOS/ccbResources/Flavors.ttf

**Warning:** Parameter Source/Resources/Published-iOS/ccbResources/Flavors.ttf was not found in asset.

**in console I type:** apportable log

**WARNING:** Trying to load font 'Flavors' but loaded 'Roboto'

**WARNING:** Registered fonts: - 
other font names....
then it shows my font im looking for!!!
**08-19 13:13:12.872 17108 17121 D testAndroid7: Flavors,**

one of the Nice guys on apportable gave me this tip:
as apparently the error is with the cocos2d headers, so he has made a patch
id di work for some people - unfortunately not me!)
https://gist.github.com/ebrodzki/70edbf926056b30a4fce

So here I run the patch

iMac:~ Minty$ patch /Users/Minty/Desktop/CustomFontTest.spritebuilder/Source/libs/cocos2d-iphone/cocos2d/CCLabelTTF.h /Users/Minty/Desktop/untitled\ folder/gistfile1.txt

patching file /Users/Minty/Desktop/CustomFontTest.spritebuilder/Source/libs/cocos2d-iphone/cocos2d/CCLabelTTF.h

I have this error:

Can't find file to patch at input line 18
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:

|diff --git a/Source/libs/cocos2d-iphone/cocos2d/CCLabelTTF.m b/Source/libs/cocos2d-iphone/cocos2d/CCLabelTTF.m
|index 9d641d2..182e4b5 100644
|--- a/Source/libs/cocos2d-iphone/cocos2d/CCLabelTTF.m
|+++ b/Source/libs/cocos2d-iphone/cocos2d/CCLabelTTF.m

In xcode it gives me this error:

I used this cool script found on apportable to locate the error in xcode
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/mgwu-misc/debugging-tutorial/add_break.py | python

Anyhelp would really be appreciated!
with thanks
N

[image]